# Why would an R package load random numbers?

Tags: r, package, random-seed, reproducible-research

Recently, I was reading the documentation for the `caret` package when I noticed this:

> Also, please note that some packages load random numbers when loaded (directly or via namespace) and this may effect [*sic*] reproducibility.

What are possible use cases for packages loading random numbers? This seems to be counter to the idea of reproducible research and might interfere with my own attempts to `set.seed`. (I've started setting seeds closer to code that requires random number generation precisely because I'm worried about the side effects of loading packages.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One example of a package that does this is [`ggplot2`](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2), as mentioned by [Hadley Wickham](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16632/hadley) in a response to a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/tidyverse/tidyverse/issues/29) related to [`tidyverse`](https://github.com/tidyverse/tidyverse).

When the package is attached, a tip is randomly selected to be displayed for the user (and with some probability, no tip is displayed). If we examine its `.onAttach()` function [as it existed before January 2018](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/blob/deb193648dd06d46f8fd5092dff74f05b7944a8c/R/zzz.r), we see it calls both `runif()` and `sample()`, changing the seed:

```
.onAttach <- function(...) {
  if (!interactive() || stats::runif(1) > 0.1) return()

  tips <- c(
    "Need help? Try the ggplot2 mailing list: http://groups.google.com/group/ggplot2.",
    "Find out what's changed in ggplot2 at http://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/releases.",
    "Use suppressPackageStartupMessages() to eliminate package startup messages.",
    "Stackoverflow is a great place to get help: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/ggplot2.",
    "Need help getting started? Try the cookbook for R: http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/",
    "Want to understand how all the pieces fit together? Buy the ggplot2 book: http://ggplot2.org/book/"
  )

  tip <- sample(tips, 1)
  packageStartupMessage(paste(strwrap(tip), collapse = "\n"))
}

release_questions <- function() {
  c(
    "Have you built the book?"
  )
}
```

However, this has since [been fixed](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/pull/2409) with a commit authored by [Jim Hester](https://github.com/jimhester) so that the seed is reset after `ggplot2` is attached:

```
.onAttach <- function(...) {
  withr::with_preserve_seed({
    if (!interactive() || stats::runif(1) > 0.1) return()

    tips <- c(
      "Need help? Try the ggplot2 mailing list: http://groups.google.com/group/ggplot2.",
      "Find out what's changed in ggplot2 at http://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/releases.",
      "Use suppressPackageStartupMessages() to eliminate package startup messages.",
      "Stackoverflow is a great place to get help: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/ggplot2.",
      "Need help getting started? Try the cookbook for R: http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/",
      "Want to understand how all the pieces fit together? Buy the ggplot2 book: http://ggplot2.org/book/"
      )

    tip <- sample(tips, 1)
    packageStartupMessage(paste(strwrap(tip), collapse = "\n"))
  })
}
```

So, there could be various reasons why a package does this, though there are ways that package authors can prevent this from giving unexpected consequences to the user.

Comment: That's a great example. Thanks! I wonder if there's an easy way to generate a list of all package that include some kind of random process when attached.

Comment: @SeanRaleigh Glad it helped. That sounds like another great question to post on SO

Comment: Done: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49711972/which-r-packages-use-some-kind-of-random-process-when-attached